# Sharing network: windows host act as router for guests?

Tags: networking, windows-7, routing, virtualbox

I want to pin my guest system to existing network - they must get ip from this same dhcp server like host and can communicate with host and other through this network. Can i do that and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Settings->Network->Adapter 1->Attached to: **Bridged adapter**

And choose the interface which is connected to your existing network (usually Local Area Connection or whatever it is called on the host machine)